# Is it possible to replicate _users in CouchDB with a non-admin user, but "users_db_public = true"?

Tags: couchdb, database-replication

Via a non-admin user, I am able to `GET` any user with `users_db_public = true` and `public_fields` set to something valid without authorization problems, as expected.
However I am getting `401 (Unauthorized)` errors when trying full replication via pouchdb or curl.
My request URL looks like:

`https://my.couchdb.server.ipaddr/_users/_changes?timeout=25000&style=all_docs&heartbeat=10000&since=0&limit=100`

I would expect replication to work with the above configs in local.ini and returning a copy of _users filled with the defined `public_fields` as it does with a single or bulk `GET` of a user doc.

Sure I could manually bulk fetch all relevant user docs and then work with them, but using the replication feature would have multiple advantages (readability, stability, performance).

If it's not possible for a good reason, that would be interesting to know as well.

Answer (score 0):

What version of CouchDB is this?

I think the answer is that you must be an admin to get `_changes` in the users db.

Comment: It's version 1.6.1.
You could be right, but I havent found any official or unofficial documentation on it, but could have possible looked in the wrong places.